# SMS option not working properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sms

I am using xcode 4.2 and i am developing an  iphone APP , part of this app is sending SMSs

here is the code that I typed:

```
-(IBAction)SMSbutton{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *sms = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
            sms.body= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"text"];
            sms.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            [self presentModalViewController:sms animated:YES];
}
```

I can open the SMS application and send SMS but the problem is whether I click on the "cancel" or the "send" button the message application does not go away . how to do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set your calling class to be a delegate of the message composer, then catch the cancel and send events to dismiss the modal view controller as needed.

Set your header file to adhere to the MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, and when you initialize the composer, set the message delegate to self:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *george = [MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
george.messageComposeDelegate = self;
```

Then implement the delegate method...easiest way is:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{   
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

...but you can catch and deal with errors and events as necessary.

Comment: i did the delegate part , but how to make it cancel the cancel and send events ?

Comment: Updated my answer, please see above.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Would appreciate it if you could mark the answer as accepted, if at all possible.  One of the answers, anyway!  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:` in your delegate"

```
-(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
      if(result == MessageComposeResultCancelled) {
           //Message cancelled
      } else if(result == MessageComposeResultSent) {
           //Message sent
      }

      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`?

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```